# Como ler XML com PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

Olá estou começando a aprender PHP, e criei um input HTML que recebe um arquivo XML que deve ser lido no PHP porem estou tendo dificuldades, eu estou usando o `simplexml_load_file` mais quando eu chamo os dados do xml não retorna nada assim como nesse print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Gostaria de saber como posso resolver?**

Meu código: (index.php)

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="teste.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="myfile">coloque o arquivo XML:</label>
    <input type="file" id="myfile2" name="myfile2"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

(teste.php)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
 $myfile2 = $_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'];
 $dados_xml = simplexml_load_file($myfile2);
 echo $dados_xml
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: você quer mostrar o xml na tela?

Comment: isso mesmo o conteúdo do xml, na verdade só alguns campos mas pra inicio sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código está errado, porque, não vai mostrar o resultado em tela, sendo que a função [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file) retorna um objeto do tipo [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php) que é incompreendido pelo navegador e o que é necessário é o conteúdo simples desse [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) e mudar a cabeça da página para `Context-type: text/xml`, então abra o arquivo com a função `fopen` leia o seu conteúdo com `fread` e feche o seu ponteiro com `fclose` e por fim envie o conteúdo que o navegador vai compreender por causa da configuração do seu `Content-type`, ***exemplo***:

```
function load_xml()
{
  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  $filename = $_FILES['myfile2']['tmp_name'];
  $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $conteudo = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
  fclose($handle);
  return $conteudo;
}

echo load_xml();
```

Comment: Agradeço por esclarecer